# connecting from red hat 6.4 to MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, perl, redhat

I am trying to connect from my red hat 6.4 to a MSSQL 2012 server to monitor some parameters.

Long story short:
I have Icinga 1.9.4 configured on that Red Hat and I am monitoring lots of hosts/services. 
Also successfully monitoring MSSQL 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 with check_mssql_health (and freetds) from labs.consol.de

The problem appears when trying to monitor MSSQL 2012, plugin cannot connect to it.
Asked my MSSQL admin to double check that everything is configured OK, he confirmed that, he also successfully connected to MSSQL 2012 from another working MSSQL 2008.
So, I thought, I should at least make a connection from anything (perl, isql, tsql)  to see if actually is working and that I can get some data from that server but nothing can connect.

Perl/isql/tsql cannot connect also to working MSSQL servers (the ones that I am successfully monitoring with Icinga / check_mssql_health) so I am guessing the problem is my linux setup.

I could (desperately) use your help in finding out what the problem is.

I do not know if check_mssql_health is compatible with MSSQL 2012 server, but, if I could make a successful connection from Perl to that MSSQL 2012, I should be able to get what I need with the help of Perl.

Some details of my setup:

```
perl -MDBI -e 'DBI->installed_versions;'
  Perl            : 5.010001    (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)
  OS              : linux       (2.6.18-398.el5)
  DBI             : 1.633
  DBD::mysql      : 4.013
  DBD::Sybase     : 1.15
  DBD::Sponge     : 12.010003
  DBD::Proxy      : 0.2004
  DBD::Oracle     : 1.74
  DBD::ODBC       : 1.50
  DBD::Gofer      : 0.015327
  DBD::File       : 0.44
  DBD::ExampleP   : 12.014311
  DBD::DBM        : 0.08



 cat /etc/odbc.ini
[SASSQL26DEV]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = MSSQL database pt serverul meu
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /usr/local/src/traceFile.log
# Servername corresponds to the section in freetds.conf
Servername = SASSQL26DEV
Database = tempdb
#port = 1433



cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[PostgreSQL]
Description             = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64                = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage               = 1

[MySQL]
Description             = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64                = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage               = 1

[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so



cat /usr/local/freetds/etc/freetds.conf

[SASSQL26DEV]
        host = 10.101.1.39
        #port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        instance = CRMDEV
```

The following Nagios user is a domain user

```
isql -v SASSQL26DEV DOMAIN\nagios 'password'
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The following testnagios user, is a MSSQL user

```
isql -v SASSQL26DEV testnagios 'ZAQ!2wsx'
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect


cat 11sql2012_test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;

my $user   = "nagios";
my $passwd = "password";
my $server = "SASSQL26DEV";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Sybase:server=$server", $user, $passwd, {PrintError => 0});
my $sth;

unless ($dbh) {
    die "ERROR: Failed to connect to server ($server).\nERROR MESSAGE: $DBI::errstr";
} else {
    print "\n";
    print "Successful Connection.";
    print "\n\n";
}


./11sql2012_test.pl
ERROR: Failed to connect to server (SASSQL26DEV).
ERROR MESSAGE:  at ./11sql2012_test.pl line 13.
```

Thanks

Comment: You can find more debugging information using export DBI_TRACE=1 environment variable. There is several levels of debugging info, from 1 to 15.